# how to activate google cloud free trail account after getting the error in payment profile (OR-BSBBF-103)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

After successfully giving the OTP from the bank the error is coming and a popup is coming saying "This action couldn't be completed. Try again later.(OR-BSBBF-103).
What should I do next?
Please guide me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is off-topic and not programming nor software dev related.

Comment: facing the same issue , any one found a fix for this ?